# Typescript define arbitrary function with void return tupe

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I want to write some decorator function, taking function as an argument:

```
type SomeType = ??? => void;

const decorate = (fn: SomeType): SomeType => {
   ...
}
```

Ho do I define "SomeType", to limit *decorate* call only on functions, having void return type?

```
const f1 = decorate((a: number) => {console.log(a);});   //OK
const f2 = decorate((a: number, b: string) => {console.log(a,b);}); //OK
const f3 = decorate((a: number, b: number) => {console.log(a,b); return a+b;});  //Not allowed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the problem. Preserving argument types through the `decorate` function. And ensuring the return type of the decorated function is `void`

The first part you can solve by adding a generic argument to `decorate`. This will make a call to `decorate` capture the actual arguments:

```
const decorate = <A extends any[]>(fn: (...a: A) => void): (...a: A) => void => {
   return fn;
} 

const f1 = decorate((a: number) => {console.log(a);});   //(a: number) => void;
const f2 = decorate((a: number, b: string) => {console.log(a,b);}); //(a: number, b: string) => void;
const f4 = decorate((a: number, b: number) => {console.log(a,b); return a+b;}); //(a: number, b: number) => void;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=70&pln=1&pc=71#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgU1AJwIZQTAvDAPAQRgQA8Mw4IZUwBPAbQF0A+ACgDMwAuGFgOn9Td8ASmxMYANxABLOMO58BQ0VnFTZYmAG8AsACgYh5AigBXZGBgcA3PoC+MfftCRYbAIzZ4SEGgwsWQRgwUwBbACMEZBVxLRcIEAAbBF5EkABzQOFrO2zDRz14twAmL0QUdAQAoJCIqIAaGHDuaGRpMHSY7XiklLTM1Hrw7NzrAqKrABYynz8qwO5ayORG5uCw5a648ATk1IzAobzjMwsqAGpwnOygA)

The second part is a bit more tricky, `void` in a signature does not necessarily mean the function will not return a value, but rather that any returned value will not be observed by the caller. While there are some safeguards when declaring a function with an explicit return of `void` (ex: `function x(): void { return 1 }`), generally a function returning anything, can be assigned to a signature that requires `void`

```
function x() { return 1 }
let y : () => void = x
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwBQEpEG9ECcCmUIuSAjIgL4CwAUADaGICeiAXIhogLwB8iAbnBgATbiiA)

That being said, since you do need this in another function (the `decorate` function) we can capture the actual return type of whatever function you pass in, and use a conditional type to force a kind of custom error:

```
const decorate = <A extends any[], R>(fn: ((...a: A) => R & (void extends R ? unknown : ["Void required allowed"]))): (...a: A) => void => {
   return fn;
} 

const f1 = decorate((a: number) => {console.log(a);});   //OK
const f2 = decorate((a: number, b: string) => {console.log(a,b);}); //OK
const f3 = decorate((a: number, b: number) => {console.log(a,b); return a+b;}); //    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '["Void required allowed"]'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgU1AJwIZQTAvDAPAQRgQA8Mw4IZUwBPAbQF0AaGAJQD4AKAMzAC4YnTgDpRqAfgCU2dmxgAyQQDcQASzhFSCcpVYwA-DACuYANZgQAdzAwBdAEQA1NRuQIAjkdVuNqADZ+Vghw9gyS4QIiYhLSWLIq6jIwAN4AsABQMFluUEbINrwA3BkAvjAZGaCQsNwAjNjwSCBoGELiMGBGALYARgjIsbLJVRAgfgjCgQDmnKiShSXzWTAA9CsA8gDSleDQMNwATA2IKOgIbQKdvf0sPQLQyKpgU4MpI2MT07NMPfOLhasNtt0iMagBmY5NFrnWaXbp9ZC3OHXAZJYa7D6TEAzVA-JY5PI2VAAah6CyWa2WMAAKjQAA6YADkVwRjJgqkoFlgqAgEFUUzAqB64xgUBAovpTIczkSbk83mCVACQRCDEZwiAA)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
type SomeType = (...args: any) => void;
```

I will link this though as it is relavent to your case, it will not throw an error if you put in a function that does not have a void return type https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void

Comment: Right, this could make the compiler keep silent, but I wouldn't loose the type here. These type looses make TypeScript degrade to JavaScript

Comment: If you want to be able to add parameters to the callback function you have to define _some_ type to the function argument. And you can define variable amont of like `type SomeType = (...args: any[]) => void;`. But if you want to strict your arguments (like you want to add just numbers to the callback) you can: `type SomeType = (...args: number[]) => void;`. This way variable amount of numbers will be accepted as arguments.